# Cscope output window shows only one line

Tags: vim, cscope

I installed Cscope thru Vundle, and I didn't do any configuration.

my problem is

After searching with `sccope find`, I got only **one line** output window at the bottom, and 
automatiically move the first matching.

```
(1 of 2): <<getFoo>> int XObjectName::getFoo()
```

How can I show all the matching list?

Comment: Why did you install this plugin? Vim already has `cscope` support if built correctly. Also, the answer is certainly in `:h cscope`.

Comment: oh thanks, romainl. I installed 'cscope.vim' plugin thru vundle, after uninstall 'cscope.vim'.  original cscope works fine, thanks again!